# Why Cant add a class to an element by jquery

Tags: theming, javascript

In the page.tpl.php I have some elements like

```
<div class="play"></div>
```

I have linked js file to the page and it is correctly works since all functions operate based on click attributes. but I would like to mudify some elements in page.tpl.php page. for example in my JS file I have a code like this:

```
$(".play").attr("id", "myID");
```

I could not make it working. basically it does not add `myID` to `.play`.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you wrap your javascript as documented here: [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on little information provided its probably because you cannot access jQuery with the $ by default in drupal.  This is to prevent other library conflicts (see [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/))  If this is the case you will probably be getting an undefined function error in your console.  To fix this you can either use jQuery or wrap it in a function like this:

```
(function($){
  $(".play").attr("id", "myID");
})(jQuery);
```

or can do this:

```
jQuery(".play").attr("id", "myID");
```

By default the version of jQuery that is used on drupal is 1.5.  You may consider using [jQuery Update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) for a newer version.

"Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them."